# Clarification on this submodule over $\mathbb{Z}[t]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am having trouble making the following calculation consistent. Consider the map from a $\mathbb{Z}[t]$-module to itself:

$$\phi:\mathbb{Z}[t]/I\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[t]/I,\\p(t)+I\mapsto (p(t)+I)(t^2-1),$$

where $I=(t+1)(t-n+1)\mathbb{Z}[t]$.

We know $\phi$ is a homomorphism. Thus im $\phi$ is a submodule.

Let $x=at+b+I\in\mathbb{Z}[t]/I$. Then 
\begin{align}
 \phi(x) & = (at+b)(t^2-1)+I \\
         & = (at+b)(t+1)(t-n+1+n-2)+I \\
         & = (n-2)(at+b)(t+1)+(at+b)(t+1)(t-n+1)+I \\
         & = (n-2)(a(t-n+1)+a(n-1)+b)(t+1)+I\\
         & = (n-2)(a(n-1)+b)(t+1)+I
\end{align}

Then I concluded that im $\phi=(n-2)(t+1)\mathbb{Z}[t]/I$.

However, every submodule of $\mathbb{Z}[t]/I$ should be a quotient like $J/I$ such that $I$ is a submodule of $J$ and $J$ is a submodule of $\mathbb{Z}[t]$. But in my calculation $I$ is not a submodule of $(n-2)(t+1)\mathbb{Z}[t]$ for $n>3$, this quotient even doesn't make sense.

Where does the flaw in my reasoning occur? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map can be written $\phi(p(t)+I)=(t^2-1)p(t)+I$. Thus the image is
$$
\bigl((t^2-1)\mathbb{Z}[t]+I\bigr)\big/I
$$
An element of the top submodule $J$ is of the form
$$
(t^2-1)f(t)+(t+1)(t-n+1)g(t)=
(t+1)\bigl((t-1)f(t)+(t-n+1)g(t)\bigr)
$$
Now
\begin{align}
(t-1)f(t)+(t-n+1)g(t)
&=(t-n+1+n-2)f(t)+(t-n+1)g(t)\\[4px]
&=(t-n+1)(f(t)+g(t))+(n-2)f(t)
\end{align}
so $J=(t-n+1)\mathbb{Z}[t]+(n-2)\mathbb{Z}[t]$ is generated by $t-n+1$ and $n-2$.

Answer (score 0):

Your first step fails; in fact
$$\phi(x)=(at+b)(t^2-1)+I(t^2-1).$$
The map $\phi$ is given by multiplication by $t^2-1$, hence its image consists of all multiples of $t^2-1$. That is to say $\operatorname{im}\phi=(t^2-1)\Bbb{Z}[t]/I$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your argument is quite straightforward. But I am not fully convinced, because $I$ is still not a submodule of $(t^2-1)\mathbb{Z}[t]$.

Comment: I should have been more clear, perhaps. I meant that
$$\operatorname{im}\phi=(t^2-1)(\Bbb{Z}[t]/I),$$
which is the same as
$$\operatorname{im}\phi=((t^2-1)\Bbb{Z}[t]+I)/I.$$
After all, the domain of $\phi$ is $\Bbb{Z}[t]/I$, so its image is the set of all multiples of $(t^2-1)$ *in $\Bbb{Z}[t]/I$*.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!